# AS3 Touch Class Examples?

Tags: actionscript-3

Anybody know any good resources for touch interface in AS3? Maybe with example downloads of simple user interface examples such as swiping lists etc. I could write code  that reacts to the mouse events but I was wondering if their is a more a intuitive way of doing it using the native touch events class? Thanks. I also believe better 3rd party classes are available but I would rather stick with the adobe classes right now unless you guys think otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Multi Touch Gesture Applications](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=119) and [Responding to Raw Touch Data](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=122) for a start.